# Does anyone have an example of using the jose library in a react app to encrypt a JWT with public key so it can be stored securely in local storage?

Tags: reactjs, encryption, jwt, rsa

I'm stuck on the jose encrypt method, can't figure out how to turn an RSA public key into a cryptoKey.

```
export const createDeluxeSession = async (session) => {
  // try {
  // convert to JSON string and then base-64 encode it
  const serializedSession = btoa(JSON.stringify(session))
  console.log('createDeluxeSession---1', serializedSession)

  // TODO this should come from the api > useLogin
  const publicKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCP7pn0NTKW3u8d6kNZ10x20F+E
Ir8PQ0jkyZSi7ze6c+w+THhGHkwuLEBfuEjwdo9zcXpweiRc2mQgLsVFnqSMm978
z1dRxZPYT3z3ynpK9mw9jNfndH3ogpJlYlXV64IcWRoCP0Bz+uOx0lXHItuiPHQn
b8oBtw2LTVevN8KO0wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

  // TODO figure out how to create a cryptoKey
  const cryptoKey = publicKey //await importKey(publicKey)

  // TODO encrypt serializedSession with cryptoKey
  const jwe = await new jose.CompactEncrypt(
    new TextEncoder().encode(serializedSession)
  )
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'RSA-OAEP-256', enc: 'A256GCM' })
    .encrypt(cryptoKey)

  // TODO store as JWE not JWT - serializedSession is not encrypted
  localStorage.setItem('deluxeSession', serializedSession)
  // } catch (e) {
  //   console.log(e)
  // }
}
```

It fails on .encrypt(cryptoKey), with the following console error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Key for the RSA-OAEP-256 algorithm must be of type CryptoKey.
    at asymmetricTypeCheck (check_key_type.js:15:15)
    at checkKeyType (check_key_type.js:42:9)
    at encryptKeyManagement (encrypt_key_management.js:15:5)
    at FlattenedEncrypt.encrypt (encrypt.js:106:56)
    at CompactEncrypt.encrypt (encrypt.js:23:43)
    at createDeluxeSession (localStorage.js:69:6)
    at Object.onSuccess (useSession.js?t=1667064963675:108:13)
    at mutation.js:92:71
```

Answer (score 2):

The posted key is a PEM encoded public RSA key in X.509/SPKI format. The [jose library](https://github.com/panva/jose) you are using supports importing a key of this format with [`importSPKI()`](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/functions/key_import.importSPKI.md#function-importspki):

```js
const publicCryptoKey = await jose.importSPKI(spkiPem, 'RSA-OAEP-256');
```

Also:

- For security reasons, RSA keys of at least 2048 bits should be used. Your RSA key is only 1024 bits and is denied by the library with a corresponding error message.
- Actually, Base64 encoding with `btoa()` is not necessary since the result of `JSON.stringify()` can be processed directly by `TextEncoder#encode()`. Therefore, if there is no explicit requirement for Base64 encoding, it can be omitted.